# Schedule Automation using script activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio

I have a case where I built a file drop automation that contains an import followed by a script activity.
Inside this file I'll be uploading a date. 
If the date matches current date, I want one automation to run (this is ok, I have a code to run an automation immediately).
But if the date does not match today, I want to schedule another automation to be runned in this date.

Please, do you guys know if it's possible to schedule an automation to run on a specific date time using Script activity? If, so, could you please, share some code?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You could use ssjs to "Perform an Automation Immediately" (which can be then used in a script activity)

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/interacting_with_automation_studio_via_the_web_service_soap_api.htm

Example below (taken from stack exchange):

[To Invoke Automation from SSJS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/250776/to-invoke-automation-from-ssjs)