# Call Apex Web Service from Cloud Page (AMPScript/SSJS)

Tags: webservices

I’ve requirement to call Sales Cloud Apex web Service from a Cloud Page. I reviewed HTTPget but it only support public webservices that doesn’t require authentication. I then researched about SOAP API but not getting a way to invoke Sales Cloud SOAP API from Cloud Page, I looked at code @ [Server-Side Javascript calling SOAP API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145139/server-side-javascript-calling-soap-api/145254), since looks link this code is to call within MC.

Any pointers?

Comment: Thanks Robs, How can I leverage Named Credentials for Call-ins? I'm trying to call Apex WebService from Marketing Cloud - Cloud Page.

Comment: Nope, Marketing Cloud only supports AMPScript and SSJS, and there documentation so vague, didn't get signle example for calling a authenticated web-service from Marketing Cloud.